# Making a tuple of nested types

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have some classes A and B:

```
struct A
{
    typedef int value_type;
};
struct B
{
    typedef float value_type;
};
```

I want to make a tuple of A::value_type and B::value type via variadic template.
I am expecting something like this:

```
template<typename ...T>
struct my_tuple
{
     typedef std::tuple<T::value_type...> tuple_type;
};
```

This doesnt compile. How can I make such kind of tuple?

Comment: Missing `typename`?

Comment: When making "my code doesn't compile" questions it is always better to paste the actual errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` is a dependent name, you need to add `typename`. like this:

```
template<typename ...T>
struct my_tuple
{
     typedef std::tuple<typename T::value_type...> tuple_type;
};
```